# Execute Ant Script with Ant Tasks Programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an Ant Script which uses Ant Task (I use this Task to execute QVTo Transformations).

The Ant Script is the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="default" xmlns:qvto="http://www.eclipse.org/qvt/1.0.0/Operational">
    <target name="default">

    <taskdef name="http://www.eclipse.org/qvt/1.0.0/Operational:transformation" classname="org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.runtime.ant.QvtoAntTransformationTask">
        <classpath>
           <pathelement location="${basedir}/libAnt/antTasks.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <qvto:transformation uri="platform:/resource/QVToTransformation/transforms/QVTTransformation.qvto">

            <in uri="platform:/resource/QVToTransformation/In/In.ecp" />  
            <out uri="platform:/resource/QVToTransformation/Out/Out.uml" />

            <trace uri="platform:/resource/QVToTransformation/Trace/trace.qvtotrace"
                generate="true" incrementalUpdate="false"  />

        </qvto:transformation>

    </target>
</project>
```

The code I use in Java to execute Ant Script is the following one:

```
File AntFile = new File(this.getClass().getResource("qvto/AntQVTo.xml").getFile());
Project p = new Project();
p.setUserProperty(
    "ant.file", 
    this.getClass().getResource("qvto/AntQVTo.xml").getFile()
    );

p.init();

ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(p, AntFile);
p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

The problem when I run my Java code is that it seems that Ant Task is not recognized at all, when I run the following error is returned:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" C:\path\to\AntTask\AntQVTo.xml:5: Problem: failed to create task or type http://www.eclipse.org/qvt/1.0.0/Operational:transformation
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
```

I don't have any problem if I execute my Ant Script directly in Eclipse, as this Task is by default defined in the Eclipse Preferences, into Ant->Runtime->Tasks.

The problem could be that Ant Script executed within Java Code isn't run as "Run in the same JRE as project".

I have that Ant Task defined in the plugin.xml which runs the Eclipse Application in the classpath, and also as an extension:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ant.core.antTasks">
    <antTask
        class="org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.runtime.ant.QvtoAntTransformationTask"
        eclipseRuntime="true"
        headless="true"
        library="libAnt/antTasks.jar"
        name="transformation"
        uri="http://www.eclipse.org/qvt/1.0.0/Operational"
        />
</extension>
```

Does anyone know how could I fix my issue?

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: Are you defining the new task anywhere in your Ant script with the `taskdef` task? See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html and https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html

Comment: I, have already added a taskdef tag, but it returns the following warning message `taskdef class org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.runtime.ant.QvtoAntTransformationTask cannot be found using 
 the classloader AntClassLoader[]` and execution also fails with the same message, I think I'm pointing to the path correctly, but I'm not sure

Comment: Looking at the `taskdef` you just added. For one thing, the name or your task should not be a URL. I can't really say what else might be wrong without having access to the jar file itself. Again, I would recommend looking at Ant's typedef documentation.

Answer (score 0):

missing Apache IVY library, Download this library from here - [apache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi)  and Copy the jar in your ant lib directory and add into class path.

- Download the jar and install Ant (e.g., C:\Apps\Tools\apache-ant-1.9).
- Download the jar and extract Ivy (e.g., C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\apache-ivy-2.4)
- Copy C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\apache-ivy-2.4\ivy-2.4.jar into C:\Apps\Tools\apache-ant-1.9\lib.

Comment: It didn't work, I downloaded the .jar for IVY (ivy-2.4.0.jar), added to the library in my eclipse project and added to the classpath, but didn't work. It is really needed to install Apache Ant? Isn't it installed by default in the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing

From:

```
<taskdef name="http://www.eclipse.org/qvt/1.0.0/Operational:transformation" classname="org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.runtime.ant.QvtoAntTransformationTask">
```

To:

```
<taskdef name="transformation" classname="org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.runtime.ant.QvtoAntTransformationTask">
```

And remove the namespace prefix to `transformation` task/element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I tried changing the name attribute to `transformation` but nothing changed.